# Semi-Hybrid Triple Channel DDR3

Tags: upgrade, memory, compatibility, ddr3, triple-channel

I have 3 x Corsair 2GB DDR3 1600MHz, and I want to expand it with 3 more DIMMs. Obviously to keep my triple-channel, I'd be best to buy an identical 3 DIMMs kit as I have now, because triple-channel doesn't work with not-identical memory DIMMs, but to what level of difference?

Can I have identical spec DIMMs (Corsair DDR3 1600MHz) but just 4GB beside my 2GB ones, and the triple-channel will still be active?

Answer (score 1):

You need three DIMMs for triple channel, regardless of their specifications (they'll all run at the speed of the slowest DIMM). However, for desktop usage, triple channel offers no benefit at all - thus you can go with an even number of DIMMs and they will run in dual channel mode.

Comment: Who told you that? I have a motherboard that supports 4 DIMMs in 3-channel mode, http://superuser.com/questions/582670/combining-multiple-dimms-in-one-memory-channel

Comment: Ohh, I remember. You preferred to remove the reference to the philosphical aspect of your statement, http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/6561/3484